# Bold and normal text next to each other not aligned because of font: helvetica

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts

I have to texts next to each other, the first one is bold and the next one has normal font-weight. But the texts bottom is not aligned, the text with normal font weight is about 1 px up in Chrome.

One solution could be to compensate this with `margin-top: 1px;` on the text with normal font-weight but firefox and chrome seems to handle this differently because of the font:

`font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;`

Any suggestions how to solve this without browser specific css and not changing the font.

Open this example in both FF and Chrome: [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dqdLrud7/3/)

Html:

```css
.bold-text, .normal-text {
   display: inline-flex;
   font-size: 12px;
}

.top-wrapper {
   margin-top: 2px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.bold-text {
   font-weight: bold;
   max-width: 115px;
 }

 .normal-text {
   color: #777;
   margin-left: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="top-wrapper">
    <div class="bold-text">some random text</div>
    <div class="normal-text">6 days ago</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try Giving text-shadow for .normal text class like text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #777; for making same line....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `align-items: center;` in flexbox

```css
.bold-text, .normal-text {
   display: inline-flex;
   font-size: 12px;
}

.top-wrapper {
   margin-top: 2px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   font-family: Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
   align-items: center;
}

.bold-text {
   font-weight: bold;
   max-width: 115px;
 }

 .normal-text {
   color: #777;
   margin-left: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="top-wrapper">
    <div class="bold-text">some random text</div>
    <div class="normal-text">6 days ago</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

For me replacing

```
Helvetica Neue
```

with

```
Helvetica Neue Regular


font-family: Helvetica Neue Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
```

is working.

```css
.bold-text, .normal-text {
   display: inline-flex;
   font-size: 12px;
}

.top-wrapper {
   margin-top: 2px;
   display: flex;
   flex-direction: row;
   font-family: Helvetica Neue Regular,Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
}

.bold-text {
   font-weight: bold;
   max-width: 115px;
 }

 .normal-text {
   color: #777;
   margin-left: 3px;
 }
```

```html
<div class="top-wrapper">
    <div class="bold-text">some random text</div>
    <div class="normal-text">6 days ago</div>
</div>
```